# getScaleFromZoomLevel equivalent in Android Here-lite SDK

Tags: here-api

I want to switch from HERE Android SDK (starter/premium) to the new Lite SDK. In the previous libraries I had the function

```
public double getScaleFromZoomLevel(double level)
```

How would I get such a scale value in the Here-lite edition?

Comment: At the moment, there's no such feature. But it sounds useful. It may be possible to write your own converter utility. There are some map items that accept meters as input. From there a conversion might be possible to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I agree with Datasun. As in your previous version, the scale gives the geo distance in cm per display inch, my proposal for a function in the lite API would be something like:

DisplayMetrics appMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    map.getDisplay().getMetrics(appMetrics);

```
GeoCoordinates southWest = map.getCamera().getBoundingRect().southWestCorner;
Point2D lowerright = map.getCamera().geoToViewCoordinates(southWest);

float screenPixelPerInch = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_IN, 1, appMetrics);

Point2D yRef = new Point2D(lowerright.x, lowerright.y + screenPixelPerInch);
GeoCoordinates yRefGeo = map.getCamera().viewToGeoCoordinates(yRef);

return yRefGeo.distanceTo(southWest);
```